# Calling Global Localization Service in C++

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.  I have found [documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Services) on calling ros services using `ros::service::call` but I cannot figure out how to tell it I would like to call the `/global_localization` service that AMCL provides.

```
ros::service:call("/global_localization", ???)
```

What goes in place of the ???

I am working on a program that sends goals to the robot (using the /map frame) and I would like to call the service and have the robot drive around until it is localized instead of using RVIZ to give it a pose estimate manually.  I know that I can use `rosservice call /global_localization` but I would like to do it programmatically if at all possible.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40758/calling-global-localization-service-in-c++/) by [pdunlap2](https://answers.ros.org/users/2988/pdunlap2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosservice type /global_localization` will give you the service type to fill in there.
You can lookup the contents of the request in the API description.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0